# Как запустить DWService без входа в сессию/аккаунт на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dwservice, удалённое-управление

Нужно чтобы DWService запускался до входа в аккаунт, чтобы иметь возможность перезагружать систему и потом входить в сессию/аккаунт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто сделать симлинк на агент в директории `/etc/init.d`:

```sh
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dwagent/native/systray /etc/init.d/dwagent
```

---

Если будет возникать ошибка `Error: XWayland is not supported`, то нужно [раскомментировать](https://github.com/AG7GN/dwservice#xwayland) `#WaylandEnable=false` в `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: Во-первых, выбранное имя будет конфликтовать с уже существующей systemd-службой dwagent. Во-вторых, так как systray не является sysvinit-скриптом — попытки выполнить команды наподобие `sudo systemctl stop dwagent` будут приводить к неадекватному поведению

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за замечание. Я сделал так, как указано в ответе, и всё вроде норм работает. Решил поделиться, так как ничего не гуглится толком. Писал до этого в саппорт, чтобы спросить, но они мне не ответили.